# Create non strait forward SqlAlchemi relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 SqlAlchemy entities: study and series with 1 to many relation (study has many series). I crearted a relationship that way:

```
class SeriesDBModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "series"

    series_uid = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    study_uid = Column(String, ForeignKey(StudyDBModel.study_uid))

    study = relationship("StudyDBModel", lazy="subquery", cascade="all")

class StudyDBModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "study"

    study_uid = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

My question is:
Do I have to create the entities like this:

```
series = SeriesDBModel()
study = StudyDBModel()
series.study = study
```

Or

Can I just create both entities independently but with the same study_uid?
I'm asking because the second way i how I save my entities but using series.study returns **None**.

BTW, it's not a "sessio.commit()" issue. I'm verifing both entities exist in the DB before trying series.study..

I tried to fetch series.study as above.

Comment: The simplest way would be `series = SeriesDBModel(study=Study())`, if that works for you.

Comment: Unfurtunately I cannot, since each entity is being saved asyncrounisly through a different flow, hence the question.